# Adobe connect and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: adobe

Anyone else ever seen the issue where adobe connect just hangs while "connecting"? I've gone to the website. It tells me I don't have the addon installed. I've installed it, but it repeatedly tells me it isn't installed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Wait for it to give up on connecting.  After a few minutes, it will show something like this:

"The Meeting Room could not connect to the Adobe Connect Server.
Please re-launch the Meeting Room, or refresh your browser to
restore the connection."

There will be a link to a troubleshooting page.  Run the diagnostic tests, then click the button to "Send Results."  This will send the information to the system administrator or help desk for the Adobe Connect server.  For good measure, you might also contact them with a separate message.

(I don't know that this will really help, but it's what I did, and currrently I'm waiting for the system administrators to respond.  I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.   I found the connection test failed on my university's Adobe Connect server, but it succeeded on Adobe's test page https://arcps.adobeconnect.com/common/help/en/support/meeting_test.htm, so I'm hoping the failure was due to some misconfiguration.)

2. [Unable to join meetings at Adobe Connect?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348356/unable-to-join-meetings-at-adobe-connect/516421) asks a similar question for Ubuntu 13.04; you might find some answers there helpful.
3. Update:

My university's server administrator found this trouble is due to an unresolved bug in Adobe's Flash player; see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flashplugin-nonfree/+bug/1064353.  I had been using Firefox; he advised me to use the 3rd workaround in the bug report: use Google Chrome on Linux, with its Pepper flash player.  I had previously installed the Ubuntu chromium-browser package, and now I installed the Ubuntu package pepperflashplugin-nonfree, which provides this plugin for Chromium.  Using Chromium browser, I am now able to connect to Connect server.  Since Google now provides a deb package for Chrome, that would probably also work.

Answer (score 0):

add **?proto=true** to end of your link then tab **Open in browser**